# Form validation button without submitting the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I have a form, and I want to check validation ( if the inputs are correct) without submitting that form. How is that possible?

The validations in this example is as follows:
If the user enters **and** for first name and **jkp** for last name and clicks on the **validate** button, the document.write function will print success without submitting the form.

```js
$( "#myform" ).submit(function( event ) {
 var name = $("#fname").val();
 var lname = $("#lname").val();
 
 if(name === "and" && lname ==="jkp")
 {document.write("Correct answer");}

 else{document.write("Incorrect answer");}
});
```

```css
input[type=text], select {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=submit] {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #45a049;
}

div {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform" action="#">
    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">

    <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">


    </select>
       <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        <input style="background:red" type="submit" value="Validate">
  </form>
```

Comment: every time show the Fail

Comment: Use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent default behaviours.

Comment: or simply `return false;` cancels event default behavior (more widely supported on older browsers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**make validate but not a submit type**

Changes i have made:

in js

```
$( "#vali" ).click(function( event ) {
 var name = $("#fname").val();
 var lname = $("#lname").val();
 $('#fname, #lname').css({
        'color' : 'red'
    });
 if(name === "and" && lname ==="jkp")
 {alert("Your answers are correct!");}
 else{alert("Your answer is not correct");}
});
```

in html

```
<input id="vali" style="background:red" type="button" value="Validate">
```

**DEMO:**

```js
$( "#myform" ).submit(function( event ) {
 var name = $("#fname").val();
 var lname = $("#lname").val();
 
 if(name === "and" && lname ==="jkp")
 {alert("Your answers are correct!");}
 else{alert("Your answer is not correct");}
});

$( "#vali" ).click(function( event ) {
 var name = $("#fname").val();
 var lname = $("#lname").val();
  $('#fname, #lname').css({
            'color' : 'red'
        });
 if(name === "and" && lname ==="jkp")
 {alert("Your answers are correct!");}
 else{alert("Your answer is not correct");}
});
```

```css
input[type=text], select {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=submit] {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#vali{

    width: 100%;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}


input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #45a049;
}

div {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform" action="#">
    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">

    <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">


       <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        <input id="vali" style="background:red" type="button" value="Validate">
  </form>
```

Comment: can you change the validate to just print some inputs with red instead of alert?

Comment: print in to html element?

Comment: yes. Your example is correct, but it is always a good idea to make my validation server-side. (Not in this example)

Comment: also use document.write() not alert, please

Comment: document.write will make the whole page blank

Comment: I don't know how it will be easy to show that the form is not submitted when validate is clicked

Comment: you can redirected to your other html page using window.location.href

Comment: glad to help you

Answer (score 1):

You can also try AJAX requests supposing you will do the validation on the server side, also hiding the business logic from the client.
Another solution is to create a javascript method for validation that is called after focus lost/key up which takes the elements by their id and passes them to this function.

Comment: Here is a good example and well explained with jQuery and PHP: https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/simple-php-ajax-form-validation-example-from-scratchexample.html

Comment: @Eternal it is exactly the same way as you send emails. You take the values from the user submitting the form with jquery, and with ajax you parse those values from javascript to php. Then you do the validation process with PHP. Finally you take the values from php back to javascript with json_encode

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add `event.preventDefault()` to the submit event if the validation fails:

```js
$( "#myform" ).submit(function( event ) {
 var name = $("#fname").val();
 var lname = $("#lname").val();
 
 if(name === "and" && lname ==="jkp") {
     alert("Success");
 }
 else {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("failed");
 }
});
```

```css
input[type=text], select {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=submit] {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #45a049;
}

div {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform" action="#">
    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">

    <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">


    </select>
       <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        <input style="background:red" type="submit" value="Validate">
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not checked but you can use onchange(),
The change event occurs when the value of an element has been changed (only works on input, textarea and select elements).
The change() method triggers the change event or attaches a function to run when a change event occurs.

```
$( "#myform" ).change(function( event ) {
 var name = $("#fname").val();
 var lname = $("#lname").val();

 if(name === "and" && lname ==="jkp"){
    alert("Your answers are correct!");
 }
     else{ 
   alert("Your answer is not correct");
   }
}
```